# Replace character at specific occurrence

Tags: linux, rename

I have a bunch of files..
Here are a few. Hundreds more.

```
2019-02-08-07-32-00_UM8305_H.PDF  2019-03-17-17-59-59_UM8305_H.PDF  2019-05-05-23-59-59_UM8305_H.PDF  2019-07-08-12-31-57_UM8305_W.PDF  2019-08-20-00-01-52_UM8305_H.PDF  2019-11-07-08-26-51_UM8305_H.PDF
2019-02-08-10-07-45_UM8305_W.PDF
```

I want to replace the 10th index of `"-"` to a an `"_"`. I changed all the files to replace the `'_'` with `'-'` and then renamed it again so the `'_'` would be `'_UM8305_W.PDF'` and `'_UM8305_H.PDF'`. Now I couldn't find a way online to replace the `'-'` at a specific occurrence. I wanted to find all `'-'` and replace the 3, 6 and 7th positions if they were all `'-'`. I just used rename to replace it but can't do that for this since there are thousands of files with different months and days and replace will not do it efficiently.

Comment: Your description is confusing, there is no 10th `-` in your filenames. Could you give examples of how a few filenames may look after your transformations?

Comment: You want to change all `-` into `_`?

Comment: Sorry my description isn't really great. 2019-02-08-07-32-00-UM8305-H.PDF was the original filename. I changed the all the filenames in the directory with rename *-UM8305-H.PDF _UM8305_H.PDF. I want to change the the 3rd index of "-" (2019-02-08-07-32-00-UM8305-H.PDF) between 08-07. I meant 10th string position but it is the 3rd occurrence of the "-". Is there an easier method to only change a specific character but at different occurrences in the filename? In this case it has 7 occurences. I only wanted to change the 3rd, 6th and 7th positions from "-" to "_".

Comment: Would you [edit] the question adding and/or correcting the information, and adding an example of the result you expect? Thanks

Comment: Is this what you need (replacing `echo` fo `mv`): `for f in *.PDF; do echo ${f:0:10}_${f:11}; done`

Comment: Ah! That worked!. Can you explain this to me? If I wanted to change it in the other positions as well?

Comment: I get an error when trying "for f in *.PDF; do mv ${f:0:10}_${f:11}; done"

mv: missing destination file operand after ‘2019-11-14_18-02-08_UM8305_H.PDF’
Try 'mv --help' for more information.

Comment: Yes, the echo was for showing the result, `mv` takes two parameters, so `mv $f ${f:0:10}_${f:11}`

Comment: Yeah its just giving me an error when I replace echo with mv and not executing.

Comment: Sorry, it's not enough to replace mv for echo, you have to add the **`$f`** before `${f:0:10}_${f:11}`, because mv need two parameters: *mv file destination_file*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). It assumes the file names have the same length and follow a pattern, in this case: `YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS_rest_of_string.PDF`

```
for f in *.PDF; do
  mv $f ${f:0:10}_${f:11}
done
```

---

```
${f:0:10}
```

takes from the start of the string up to the tenth character.

---

From there add the `_` and print from the twelve character to the end:

```
_${f:11}
```

Since the count of characters starts from 0, the 11 means the 12 character.

Comment: Thank you, I was putting it all into one line. now I understand a little more thank you!